# NatTable : How to enable Auto focus functionality in a NatTable grid

Tags: nebula, nattable

I have a NatTable instance and I am trying to do something like this : Upon click of a link, one of my NatTable grid's cells should be selected (auto-focused) i.e., once the link is clicked, the cursor should be placed inside a specific cell and highlight the cell. In some threads on internet, I found that the usage of SelectCellCommand and EditSelectionCommand would help and I did the below :-

```
natTable.doCommand(new SelectCellCommand(getSelectionLayer(), 4, 0, true, true));
natTable.doCommand(new EditSelectionCommand(parent, configRegistry));
```

However, I do not see any effect. Can somebody please help me implement this? If this block of code is not giving enough information, let me know. (Here `getSelectionLayer()` gives me the Selection Layer instance)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to make a NatTable cell editable by calling an action from outside the table (via link). This is typically done via a combination of the commands you posted above. But to make this work you need to enable editing in your NatTable instance. Did you configure the NatTable to be editable?
https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=editing